# cmake can't find sudo

Tags: linux, cmake, sudo

I'm trying to run some tests via sudo as they require network admin permissions and I can't use setcap as we run several of these tests under valgrind which can't run on setcap executables. For some reason sudo isn't found. sudo works as expected when invoked from a bash terminal or from a system() call in a C application.

Example CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)

enable_testing()

add_test(NAME dummy_test
    COMMAND sudo ls
)
```

The output:

```
$ make test
Running tests...
Test project /home/cmorgan/projects/test/build
    Start 1: dummy_test
Could not find executable sudo
Looked in the following places:
sudo
sudo
Release/sudo
Release/sudo
Debug/sudo
Debug/sudo
MinSizeRel/sudo
MinSizeRel/sudo
RelWithDebInfo/sudo
RelWithDebInfo/sudo
Deployment/sudo
Deployment/sudo
Development/sudo
Development/sudo
Unable to find executable: sudo
1/1 Test #1: dummy_test .......................***Not Run   0.00 sec

0% tests passed, 1 tests failed out of 1

Total Test time (real) =   0.00 sec

The following tests FAILED:
      1 - dummy_test (Not Run)
Errors while running CTest
make: *** [Makefile:73: test] Error 8
```

I tried with the absolute path to sudo, /usr/bin/sudo with the same issue.

This looks like it may be related to sudo being a setuid application but I'm not sure exactly how to proceed.

Comment: You should probably write your test such that the test is skipped if `uid != 0 (root)`. Then it is up to the user to invoke the script as `sudo make test`. Running test as root could be tricky because you should not build any components during test but many people do. If you build something as root then a simple `make clean` will fail to clean artifacts.

Comment: I'd like the user to be prompted by sudo for the first test of several that requires sudo. I'd really prefer not to run any cmake commands under sudo for exactly the reason that you mentioned, that artifacts would be owned by root. I'd also not like to cause the user to have to go off and run them by hand, clearly that would work but wouldn't be as nice.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and it was caused by `sudo` binary not having `read` permission. If you run it, you can, but `cmake` tries to be smart and therefor fails. Workaround:

```
sudo chmod +r /usr/bin/sudo
```

An example of such system where `sudo` does not have `read` permission is Centos 6.